# x86 assembly alternative to an array

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data
    array:      dd 100000000,10000000,1000000,100000,10000,1000,100,10,1

start:           
    dec ebx                                 
    mov ecx,9                               

_loopFunction:                              
    dec ecx                                 
    dec ebx                                 
    mov dl, byte [eax + ebx]                
    sub dl, '0'                             
    push eax                                
    mov eax, 0                              
    push ebx                                
    mov ebx, 0                              
    mov ebx, dword [array + ecx*4]          
    mov eax, edx                            
    mul ebx                                 
    push ecx                                
    mov ecx, esi                            
    add ecx, eax                            
    mov esi, ecx                            
    pop ecx                                 
    pop ebx                                 
    pop eax                                 
    cmp ebx, 0                              
    jne _loopFunction                       
    mov eax, esi                            
    ret
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write this without using the array as I feel like it's somewhat clunky. Also generally any way to make this whole thing more efficient?

Must work in x86 NASM

=====

So tried moving to more movs and no pushes, and am getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) when I input a number...

```
start:              
    dec ebx                             
    mov ecx,9                           

_loopFunction:                          
    dec ecx                             
    dec ebx                             
    mov dl, byte [eax + ebx]            
    sub dl, '0'                         

    mov edi, eax
    mov ebp, ebx



;   push eax                            
;   mov eax, 0                          
;   push ebx                            
;   mov ebx, 0                          



    mov ebx, dword [array + ecx*4]      
    mov eax, edx                        
    mul ebx                             
    mov esp, ecx

;   push ecx                            

    mov ecx, esi                        
    add ecx, eax                        
    mov esi, ecx                        

    mov ecx, esp
    mov ebx, ebp
    mov eax, edi 

;   pop ecx                             
;   pop ebx                             
;   pop eax         

    cmp ebx, 0                          
    jne _loopFunction                   
    mov eax, esi                        
    ret
```

Comment: `dec ebx` at the top. here did you initialize it before decrementing it?

Comment: You only need to multiply by 10 once for each iteration of the loop. You don't need to push a register on the stack every time you use it. You don't need to initialize a register with 0 before you overwrite it with something else.

Comment: You can remove the zero initializations since they don't do anything. You'll need to rewrite your code so it doesn't need the pushes. The  Remember you have 7 registers to work with EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, EDI, ESI, and EBP a most instructions will let you use any of these.

Comment: This is now a completely different question from the original, and the comments don't really make much sense anymore. I'd recommend deleting this question and then asking a new one.

Comment: Well if people hadn't given it a bunch of negatives I would have. But because they did I can't post a new question for 3 days. Soooo gotta keep re-using this one I guess.

Comment: *Soooo gotta keep re-using this one I guess*.  No, it means you should stop and read [mcve] and [ask] so you can ask a better question next time.  People downvoted this one because they don't want to see more questions like it, and the system worked as intended by stopping you.

Comment: Is this just a string-to-integer algo, with a place-value array?  multiply by 10 and add in each step, instead of using an array of place values.  There are about a zillion string-to-integer questions on SO and elsewhere on the web.  BTW yes, your code is ridiculously clunky, and buggy too.  You appear to depend on there being a zero at the end of the array, but you only define elements down to 1.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> array1: times 10 dd 1
> ```

This definition using `times 10` is equal to

```
array1: dd 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1       ;10 times
```

---

> ```
> array2: dd 100000000,10000000,1000000,100000,10000,1000,100,10,1
> array3: dd 1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000
> ```

The arrays *array2* and *array3* are totally different because the numbers they contain are defined in a different order.

---

> Also, how is array 2 and 3 different in terms of the numbers it returns at the end of my program?

If the program processes these arrays in the same manner, then obviously the numbers returned at the end of your program will differ. **But** if you process *array2* starting at the front (working towards the end), and process *array3* starting at the end (working towards the front), then the numbers returned at the end of your program will be the same.